# subversion: setup 2 svn repositories with load balancer

Tags: svn

I am working on a project wherein there is a single subversion repository running on a machine and it frequently goes down. I have been asked to setup svn server on 2 different machines, and commits should propagate to both the svn servers simultaneously, which is running on both the machines.  I went through some links, but they insist on mirroring which involves having a master which replicates the incoming commits to the slave. But i am looking for a setup which involves a load balancer which pushes the commit to svn server running on 2 machines. Can someone please tell me how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

If your machines are connected on the same network, you can use heartbeat + drbd. 
Heartbeat for failover and drbd for replication.

Comment: Maybe go into a little more detail for this to be a really helpful answer?

Answer (score -1):

> how can this be accomplished?

Nohow